# Live Stream DJI Video to youtube in iOS

Tags: dji-sdk

I have searched a lot on this and though some samples on the Android side, I don't see any solid samples on the iOS. Seen so many like

https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift

https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/iOS-FPVDemo

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg (references) & many more.

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Based on the thread discussion, I see a few have successfully implemented. If someone could share their specific code sample from this listener to live stream the data, I am sure will be useful to everyone. Looking for ways to stream the data @ 1080p with 30fps.
or even stream from DJIVideoPreviewer.

// DJIVideoFeedListener Method

```
func videoFeed(_ videoFeed: DJIVideoFeed, didUpdateVideoData rawData: Data) {

    let videoData = rawData as NSData
    let videoBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: videoData.length)
    videoData.getBytes(videoBuffer, length: videoData.length)
    DJIVideoPreviewer.instance().push(videoBuffer, length: Int32(videoData.length))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no sample or guide to help you implement the live streaming feature using the DJI iOS or Android SDK. But it is said that in the next version of DJI Mobile SDK (Probably v4.9), will provide APIs/Samples for developers to implement video live streaming features.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how DJI Go app is implementing this feature to youtube and facebook. Is that something proprietary and not possible? Just exploring the possibilities, as I need this feature before v4.9.